# ows_DueDate missing in Sharepoint 2013 on premises

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, managed-property

I need to create a managed property for tasks DueDate field but in Add a mapping dialog I can't find it.
Am I missing something ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a list item and specify value for Due Date in the list. Then do a full crawl and wait for it to complete. Now search for duedate in crawled properties and they should show up.

Comment: Hi Nadeem. But ows_PercentComplete appears even it's not used. I will try your solution and get back with an answer.